# Getting [asymmetric] and [symmetric] back in balance

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[asymmetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asymmetric) (x49) and [symmetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symmetric) (x109) experience rather random usage in at least cryptography, recursion (?!), matrix calculation, storing data in clusters and CSS layouts. None of those have anything in common -- let's get those tags back in balance and burn them!

Crypto questions might be retagged to [encryption-symmetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption-symmetric) vs [encryption-asymmetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption-asymmetric). For the others, I mostly didn't see any use in the tag, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this request.

Here's the "About" from [symmetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symmetric):

> [symmetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symmetric) is used in its general meaning, so you are encouraged to use one or more tags in addition to this tag, to describe your case better.
>
> An example of Symmetric would be a Symmetric Key, which is used in both the sides of an algorithm in cryptography.

In other words, this tag is ambiguous and can't stand on its own to describe questions. It seems roughly split between symmetric Matrices and symmetric-key cryptography.